# How do I get the "irb(main):001:0>" prompt instead of ">>"

Tags: ruby, irb

Ruby is preinstalled on my Mac and so I wanted to have a look at it. First thing I noticed, is that irb prompts >> instead of irb(main):001:0>. I can't find anything on how to change this with Google because everyone is using irb(main):001:0> in their code ;-)

Can you help me out?

PS: It's not that I think Ruby is broken, but I want to look more nerdy while programming ;-)

Comment: also see:
[tip ruby irb auto complete](http://www.sufixo.com/raw/2006/05/29/tip_ruby_irb_auto-complete/)
<br>
[how to enable auto compleation in rubys irb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382063/how-to-enable-auto-compleation-in-rubys-irb)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ irb --help
Usage:  irb.rb [options] [programfile] [arguments]
  --prompt prompt-mode
  --prompt-mode prompt-mode
            Switch prompt mode. Pre-defined prompt modes are
            `default', `simple', `xmp' and `inf-ruby'

$ irb --prompt inf-ruby
irb(main):001:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make that into an alias in my .bashrc so I don't have to type it every time.

```
echo alias irb=\'irb --prompt inf-ruby\' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

goto the location /home/leapfrog/.rvm/scripts

```
cd ~/.rvm/scripts
```

Open the file ‘irbrc.rb’, use superuser power to over-write the

```
$ sudo gedit irbrc.rb
```

Change the content of the hash '@prompt' to the following

```
@prompt = {
 :PROMPT_I => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ", # default prompt
 :PROMPT_S => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n%l> ", # known continuation
 :PROMPT_C => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ",
 :PROMPT_N => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n?> ", # unknown continuation
 :RETURN => " => %s \n",
 :AUTO_INDENT => true
}
```

Hope this help you :)