# How to enable auto completion in Ruby's IRB

Tags: ruby, irb, tab-completion

When I use Merb's built in console, I get tab auto-completion similar to a standard bash prompt.  I find this useful and would like to enable it in non-merb IRB sessions.  How do I get auto-completion in IRB?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just drop `require 'irb/completion'` in your irbrc.

If that doesn't work try bond, http://tagaholic.me/bond/:

```
   require 'bond'; require 'bond/completion'
```

Bond not only improves irb's completion, http://tagaholic.me/2009/07/22/better-irb-completion-with-bond.html, but also offers an easy dsl for making custom autocompletions.

Comment: Works great! Minor history bug in Git Bash, but I'm sure it will be fixed.

Comment: Just wanted to add, if you are on Ubuntu, you can create the file ```.irbrc``` in your $HOME directory if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Doesnt work on OSX 10.11.5 with irb version 0.9.6(09/06/30)

Answer (score 22):

This is just repeating the information on Cody Caughlan's comment above so it is easier to find:

either `require 'irb/completion'` or add the following to `~/.irbrc`

```
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] = [] unless IRB.conf.key?(:LOAD_MODULES)
unless IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES].include?('irb/completion')
  IRB.conf[:LOAD_MODULES] << 'irb/completion'
end
```

Comment: "the page above" is a little confusing, as the order of answers can be changed. You may wish to refer to answers by the author of those answers.

Comment: Why should I add this block to the ibrc if a simple require statement does the same?

Comment: @maxschlepzig so you don't have to type `require 'irb/completion'` everytime you use or open irb =)

Comment: @M03, I parsed the sentence 'either require irb/completion or add the following to ~/.irbrc' as "either **add** require irb/completion to ~/.irbrc or add the following to ~/.irbrc'. I haven't used `irb` for years, but I still have a `~/.irbrc` which indeed starts with `require 'irb/completion'` and doesn't include any `LOAD_MODULES` stuff. And with that a history file is loaded and written fine.

Answer (score 10):

This is what worked for me on Mac OS 10.11.5. using rvm. Do the following :

1. `sudo gem install bond`
2. Create the file `.irbrc` in your home directory. `vi ~/.irbrc`
3. Add the following lines in the `.irbrc` file

   `require 'bond' 
   Bond.start`
4. Save and close the file
5. Open `irb` and use `tab` key to autocomplete